# Deserialize into map[string]interface{} as a concrete map type

Tags: json, go

```
type Foo struct {
    M map[string]interface{} `json:"m"`
}

type Bar struct {
    I int `json:"i"`
}

type Bar2 struct {
    S string `json:"s"`
}


func do() {
    concreteFoo1 := Foo {
        M: make(map[string]Bar),
    }
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"m": {"a": { "i": 1 }}}`), &concreteFoo1)

    concreteFoo2 := Foo {
        M: make(map[string]Bar2),
    }

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"m": {"a": { "s": "hello" }}}`), &concreteFoo2)

}
```

fails to compile with:

> cannot use make(map[string]Bar) (type map[string]Bar) as type
> map[string]interface {} in field value
>
> cannot use make(map[string]Bar2) (type map[string]Bar2) as type
> map[string]interface {} in field value

How can I get this to compile, and support both variants of Foo?

Comment: "How can I get this to compile, and support both variants of Foo?" You cannot. You have to decide on the type of Foo.M.

Answer (score 1):

Change `Foo.m` to be `map[string]Bar` instead of what you have, that will allow it to compile. To make it work, you need to change `Foo.m` to `Foo.M` and `Bar.i` to `Bar.I`. The Go JSON library will not unmarshal to or marshal from unexported properties. Mapping the uppercase properties to lowercase JSON elements requires using tags. Full working example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/oou2oCShBE).

Comment: Thanks @laz that will work, but the thing is, as mentioned, I don't want to change Foo. I should explain why. I have some other data `{"m": {"a": { "s": "hello" }}}` that I want to deserialize into Foo as well. I've updated the question with both variants, and included your fixes to the use uppercase field names.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:
M map[string]interface{} `json:"m"`

into :
M interface{} `json:"m"`

https://play.golang.org/p/qRxo81amA7

Comment: Yes that works. One drawback is that it loses the map type information and so map indexing requires a type assertion, eg: `concreteFoo1.M.(map[string]interface{})["a"]` Is there any way to keep the map type, with a flexible type for the value?

Answer (score 1):

If the set of possible `Bar` types is infinite you should use the solution from [Stud's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47405457/965900). After unmarshaling you just need to do one type assertion to get the `map`, which is much better then doing type assertion on each value of a `map[string]interface{}` type.

If, however, the set is limited to only a few types you could create a parent `Bar` type that embeds the list of all the possible `Bar` variations. In case there's a possibility that the fields of the embedded types would collide you can still have the embedding type implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface and do some custom logic on what to unmarshal where.

E.g. something like this:

```
type BarSet struct {
    *Bar
    *Bar2
}

type Bar struct {
    I int `json:"i"`
}

type Bar2 struct {
    S string `json:"s"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/tJfqtnP-CX

And if you want to be as strict as possible you should create separate `Foo` types, each with their distincitve `M map[string]...` field.

Comment: What is the memory layout of an instance of Bar or Bar2, does it always have two slots for the two pointers?

Comment: If you're asking about size, yes, an instance of `BarSet` with both pointers `nil` will have a size of 8 (4 each).

Answer (score 0):

You can make generalized interface

```
type Foo struct {
    M map[string]Ibar `json:"m"`
}

type Ibar interface{}
```

And unpack into it.

When you need specific value of variable make type assertion.

https://play.golang.org/p/fcs-Yp-ck2

Answer (score 0):

I've looked again and think custom unmarshaler can be good option.

```
func (f *Foo) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var tmp struct {
        M map[string]json.RawMessage `json:"m"`
    }
    var foo = Foo{
        M: make(map[string]interface{}),
    }
    var err error
    //for key, rawValue := range
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &tmp)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for key, rawValue := range tmp.M {
        var bar Bar
        if json.Unmarshal(rawValue, &bar) == nil && bar.I != 0 { // custom check
            foo.M[key] = bar
            continue
        }
        var bar2 Bar2
        if json.Unmarshal(rawValue, &bar2) == nil && bar2.S != "" { // custom check
            foo.M[key] = bar2
            continue
        }
    }
    *f = foo
    return nil
}
```

Advantages:

- Logics in one place
- Standard call `UnmarshalJSON`
- Can handle several subobjects

https://play.golang.org/p/ug9rewqjWw